# Message box Yes/No response are the same

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a spreadsheet for recording use of propshafts in engine testing. On a user form they record which propshaft is installed or removed and the spreadsheet updates everything automatically. As part of this I want it to flag up automatically when they are trying to install a propshaft that may previously have been scrapped but also allow them to continue (there may be some reason for it being used beyond normal use). To this end I've set it up to open a message box with a Yes/No option to continue if the propshaft is recorded as scrapped but the same result is happening no matter what button is selected.

```
ElseIf Installbutton = True And Locationtext = "Scrapped" Then

MsgBox "This Propshaft is showing as Scrapped" & vbNewLine & "Do you wish to continue with the install?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion

    If vbYes Then
    GoTo 10
    Else
    Exit Sub
    End If

Else
```

So not matter what button is pressed it continues as if you pressed yes and runs the rest of the sub. I've changed the code so that vbNo is first but then no matter what button you press it exits the sub. I've also tried using the numbers for vbYes or vbNo but that made no difference.

I've also tried doing answer = messagebox("blah, blah, blah") and if answer = vbYes and so on but that made no change.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, any suggestions?

Comment: `GoTo 10` - really? I haven't used that line of code since programming in Basic on the Compucolor II.

Comment: A number by itself shows up very clearly when I'm looking through the lines of the code.

Comment: If you need to look for a number when reviewing your code, then your code structure is fundamentally wrong. This is classic spaghetti coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the user's 'answer' to a variable and test that variable:

```
uinput = MsgBox("Answer yes or no", vbYesNo)

If uninput = vbYes Then
    'Do something
ElseIf uninput = vbNo Then
    'Do something else
End if
```

Note that I have added parentheses around the arguments for the `MsgBox` function, as this is necessary when populating a variable with a function.

Answer (score -1):

There's no big problem, you have simply misunderstood how to process the result of the `MsgBox` command.

The `MsgBox` command returns the result indicating which button was clicked by the user.  Try this code out and you will see that it works:

```
If MsgBox("This Propshaft is showing as Scrapped" & vbNewLine & "Do you wish to continue with the install?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
    Goto 10
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

You could also capture the result in a variable and process it if you had several outcomes, as the solution above is only suitable where you are testing for `vbYes` only.